# Converting Date Text into Date Values in R (i.e. September 30, 1962 into 9/30/1962)?

Tags: r, date

I have a vector that stores dates as text (i.e. September 30, 1962). I want to get this into date format in R. More concretely, I have a vector that currently stores strings, and there is possibility of empty strings. I would like to convert the vector into date.

For example, I have a vector called

```
date = c("September 30, 1962", "June 04, 1938", "", "August 18, 1946")
```

Currently this is a string vector, I would like to convert this into a date vector with values

```
c(9/30/1962, 6/04/1938, NA, 8/18/1946)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best,

Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
library(lubridate)
format(mdy(date), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

If you need to remove the `0` from the "month"

```
sub('^0', '', format(mdy(date), '%m/%d/%Y'))
#[1] "9/30/1962" "6/04/1938" NA          "8/18/1946"
```